# ActiveStorage image not showing in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I've followed the rails ActiveStorage guide. I've successfully saved the image to the blob table in the local database (the attachment table is empty). But I can't seem to show it in the view:

```rb
<%= url_for(@comment.images) if @comment.images %>
```

does not work nor does:

```rb
     <% @comments.each do |c| %>
        <%= c.body %>

        <%= url_for(c.images) if c.images %>

      <% end %>
```

Showing other values of comment works, so this is specific to the images. I've also tried adding .url to "images." And I've tried image_tag instead of url_for. No luck in both cases. I'd really appreciate any help.

And my model

```rb
  has_many_attached :images
```

application.js

```js
//= require activestorage


import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"


Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

controller

```rb
    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:body, images: [])
    end
```

Comment: Is `images` really plural? If so you will need to loop through them.

Comment: @RockwellRice Thank you for the comment. I've tried ```<% c.images.each do |i| %>
          <%= url_for(i) %>
        <% end %>``` But no use. Also tried image_tag and without any, just "i"

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Add the model and how you have setup the attachment

Comment: @amazingbot  That is fine, but if it is plural then you do need to loop through it no matter what, your solution comes inside a loop.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Thank you for the comment. I've updated the question.

Comment: You sure? https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Many.html this says there should be something there. Also I know this is late.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use activestorage *representation* method. Try this:

```
<% @comments.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.body %>
  <% c.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag image.representation(resize: '500x500') %>
  <% end %>
    
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried it just now. Same so far.